# VB.Net to AccessDB by SQL - INSERT INTO with parameters error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

The following code has one `update` and one `insert` statement, using the same parameters. The update function WORKS, the Insert into statement does not... (in update, all parameters are successfully set in the DB)

I won't post the rest of connection string, as this already is set up and working.

I receive the following error: *Data type mismatch in criteria expression.*

```
Dim UpdateCon As MasterConnection = New MasterConnection()
Dim myCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand = UpdateCon.GetConnection().CreateCommand
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Navn", BoxKundeNavn.Text)) 'text field'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Hendelsesdato", DtpHendelsesdato.Value.ToString)) 'datetimepicker'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Event", BoxTrojans.Text)) 'text field'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Annet", BoxLogg.Text)) 'text field'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@EndretAv", Analyst.ToString)) 'string variable'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@EndretDato", Date.Now().ToString)) 'datetime picker'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Kontaktet", contacted)) 'boolean'
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@BrukerID", BoxKundeID.Text)) 'text field'

If userExist = True Then
    Dim SqlText As String = "Update master Set Navn= @Navn, Hendelsesdato= @Hendelsesdato, Event= @Event," & _
                "Annet= @Annet, EndretAv= @EndretAv, EndretDato=@EndretDato, Kontaktet=@Kontaktet WHERE BrukerID= @BrukerID"
    myCommand.CommandText() = SqlText
Else
    intCheck = MsgBox("Du er nå i ferd med å legge til en ny unik kundeID i database, er dette riktig?", vbYesNo, "Ny kundeID")
    If intCheck = True Then
        Dim SqlText As String = "INSERT INTO master (Hendelsesdato, BrukerID, Navn, Event, Annet, Kontaktet, EndretDato, EndretAv) " & _
                    "VALUES (@Hendelsesdato, @BrukerID, @Navn, @Event, @Annet, @Kontaktet, @EndretDato, @EndretAv)"
        myCommand.CommandText() = SqlText

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Dim test As Integer
Try
    UpdateCon.GetConnection.Open()
    test = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    UpdateCon.GetConnection.Close()
Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: What is the `BrukerID` if the user doesn't exist? Is this automatically generated in the database - you are explicitly setting it in your `insert` statement.

Comment: The BrukerID or UserID is given in parameter list.

Comment: Yes I know, that's exactly my point - what value does it have when the user does not exist?

Comment: When the user does not exist, the field will be filled manually by the user, and will contain data. this is checked further up in the program to see that it is not left blank (all fields are checked). The AccessDB is also a text field, and the BrukerID will contain 11 numbers or some letters+numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it did not fix the problem, (all it wanted was to add CTypes in front of some variables and calls). I will continue to search code ;)

Comment: If anyone is interested, i found the problem. The parameters MUST be added with .add in the same order as they are to be used in the code.... why i have no idea. but that made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Access.OLEDB **ignores** parameter names; the parameters must be defined in the *exact* order that they appear in the command text. Since your two commands use the same parameters *in a different order* you'll have to use separate blocks of code to define the parameters for each one.